# How can I return a variable contained in a block loop to a method in pharo

Tags: smalltalk, pharo, pharo-5

Say I have a method which implements a do:[] every:40s block. There is in the block a value data that should be returned at at every delay. How can I retun this to the method in pharo as follow:

```html
Class>>updateMethod

"This is a method"
| scheduler data |
scheduler := TaskScheduler new.
scheduler start.
"refresh every 40 seconds"
scheduler
   do: [a get: 'https://MyServer/json'.
        Transcript show: 'Refreshing......'; cr.
        data := NeoJSONReader fromString: a contents; cr.
   every: 60 seconds
```

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your question, the issue here would be that you cannot use an expression such as `^data` to return the received data because the return operator `^` would exit the block.

So, to achieve the desired behavior you need to *send* the received `data` in a message. Something on the lines of:

```
| scheduler data |
scheduler := TaskScheduler new.
scheduler start.
scheduler
  do: [a get: 'https://MyServer/json'.
    Transcript show: 'Refreshing......'; cr.
    data := NeoJSONReader fromString: a contents; cr.
    self processData: data].
  every: 40 seconds.
```

In this way, at every evaluation of the block, your code will have the chance to receive new `data` and *process* it properly.

**Addendum:** The selector `processData:` is nothing but a hint or placeholder for the actual message that will do something with the data just read. In other words, you should create such a method and put there whatever processing is required in your application for the data. Something like

```
processData: data
  self
    validateData: data;
    doSomethingWith: data;
    "...blah..."
```

Comment: where does processData come from? is it some kind of message I must create?

Comment: @ludo yep, you got it. :)

Comment: As @lurker said, you have to create such a method. I've added this clarification to my answer.

Comment: waaw thanks,  it is nice to learn new technics @LeandroCaniglia